# How do I convert web application developed using django into desktop executable?

Tags: python, web-applications, desktop-application

I've have developed a web application using Django, python, HTML, CSS. Is it possible to create executable/installer for Windows operating system? It should look like native application, with a desktop icon, and when clicked it should launch in any browser given its a web application. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to have the whole server packaged or do you want to run the server centralized (one Django, many computers) and have a packaged client?

Comment: Take a look at electron: https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Hi! The idea is to deploy this application in a server and make it available to multiple users on their laptops. I'm not sure if this is in regards to the above question about converting the application into an executable file? Please help me out here.

Comment: Django-html-css are for web stack! for desktop native apps try other languages!

Comment: Well it might be possible if you will render it with some kind of `WebView`. But Django is not meant to be desktop application better idea would be to use other libraries.